# Cannot install the gpu version of torch and torchvision in poetry due to a dependency problem

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, python-poetry

I am trying to create a virtual environment for machine learning using poetry. So, I am using pytorch as a framework for deep learning. I will extract the relevant part of my pyproject.toml.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies].
python = "^3.8"
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch-1.8.0%2Bcu111-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl"}
torchvision = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torchvision-0.9.0%2Bcu111-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl" }
```

Since pytroch uses the GPU, you need to install it by specifying the whl file. If you install it this way, the version of `pytroch` will be `1.8.0+cu111`. `torchvision` corresponding to `1.8.0` of pytorch is `0.9.0`. The version of pytroch that this `torchvision` depends on is `1.8.0` (without `cu111`). Therefore, I cannot create a virtual environment using poetry with the following error.

```
  SolverProblemError

  Because torchvision (0.9.0) depends on torch (1.8.0)
   and mdwithpriorenergy depends on torch (1.8.0+cu111), torchvision is forbidden.
  So, because mdwithpriorenergy depends on torchvision (0.9.0), version solving failed.

So, because [env name] depends on torchvision (0.9.0), version solving failed.
```

I also made the following changes to torchvision in pyproject.toml above, but they did not work.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies].
python = "^3.8"
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch-1.8.0%2Bcu111-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl"}
- torchvision = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torchvision-0.9.0%2Bcu111-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl"}
+ torchvision = "*"
```

In this case, I received the following error

```
  AttributeError

  'EmptyConstraint' object has no attribute 'allows'.
```

Please tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this does not yet supported in poetry (without ugly hacks), see [Issue 2613](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2613).

That said, there is a fork I am maintaining called [relaxed-poetry](https://github.com/bennylut/relaxed-poetry). It is a very young fork but it supports what you want with the following configuration:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
torch = { version = "=1.8.0+cu111", source = "pytorch" }
torchvision = { version = "=0.9.0+cu111", source = "pytorch" }

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/"
secondary = true
```

If you think it can help you, you can install it side by side with poetry and use the command `rp` instead

Do note though that the installation is going to take some time as this is a large dependency and a relatively slow source..

Comment: For everyone that finds this, this is also possible with poetry now, but may depend on the poetry version 1.2.0 which is in preview right now.

Comment: @MoritzSauter can you specify how exactly it works? It does not work for me.

Comment: Pretty much as the answer here describes it (I think without the `=` in the version). As far as I can remember this depended and worked in the _preview_ version 1.2.0a. 
I since had to revert to normal poetry because of other issues with multiple sources and such, so I cannot verify right now if it still works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with normal poetry (master 1.2.0a2), it keeps trying to fetch everything from pytorch.org and failing with "Authorization error"s https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4885